# Flutter Duplicate pageview widgets

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

The error is generated every time I click the shopping cart and then return to the product, the views are duplicated and when I click return the duplicate pages appear
I do not know why the page is duplicated each time I browse and then return to the previous page, here I leave the code of

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtAMx.jpg)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SizedBox(
  width: 60,
  height: 60,
  child: RaisedButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
    shape: StadiumBorder(),
    onPressed: () {
      if (currentUser.value.apiToken != null) {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushNamed('/Cart', arguments: RouteArgument(param: '/Product', id: widget.product.id));
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Login');
      }
    },
    child: Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomEnd,
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(
          Icons.shopping_cart,
          color: this.widget.iconColor,
          size: 28,
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(
            _con.cartCount.toString(),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.merge(
                  TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: 10),
                ),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(color: this.widget.labelColor, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 15, maxWidth: 15, minHeight: 15, maxHeight: 15),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

cart code.

```
 void initState() {
_con.listenForCarts();   
_isButtonDisabled = false;
super.initState();
```

}

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async => false,
  child: Scaffold(
    key: _con.scaffoldKey,
    appBar: AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (widget.routeArgument.param == '/Product') {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Product', arguments: RouteArgument(id: widget.routeArgument.id));
          } else {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 2);
          }
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        S.of(context).cart,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.merge(TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.3)),
      ),
    ),
    body: RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: _con.refreshCarts,
      child: _con.carts.isEmpty
          ? EmptyCartWidget()
          : Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 150),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
                          child: ListTile(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                            leading: Icon(
                              Icons.shopping_cart,
                              color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              S.of(context).shopping_cart,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              S.of(context).verify_your_quantity_and_click_checkout,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ListView.separated(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          primary: false,
                          itemCount: _con.carts.length,
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return SizedBox(height: 15);
                          },
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return CartItemWidget(
                              cart: _con.carts.elementAt(index),
                              heroTag: 'cart',
                              increment: () {
                                _con.incrementQuantity(_con.carts.elementAt(index));
                              },
                              decrement: () {
                                _con.decrementQuantity(_con.carts.elementAt(index));
                              },
                              onDismissed: () {
                                _con.removeFromCart(_con.carts.elementAt(index));
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 185,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(20), topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
                        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.15), offset: Offset(0, -2), blurRadius: 5.0)]),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  S.of(context).subtotal,
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Helper.getPrice(_con.subTotal, context, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1)
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 5),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  S.of(context).delivery_fee,
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Helper.getPrice(_con.carts[0].product.market.deliveryFee, context, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1)
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  '${S.of(context).tax} (${_con.carts[0].product.market.defaultTax}%)',
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Helper.getPrice(_con.taxAmount, context, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1)
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Stack(
                            fit: StackFit.loose,
                            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: _isButtonDisabled ? null : () async {  
                                    setState(() => _isButtonDisabled = !_isButtonDisabled);
                                    await _con.updateItemsProduct();  
                                     List<Cart>  stockminimo = _con.carts.where((data) => data.quantity > int.tryParse(data.product.packageItemsCount)).toList();
                                      if(stockminimo.length == 0){
                                        if(_con.total < _con.carts[0].product.market.minimumamount){
                                            _showDialog();
                                        }else{
                                            _con.goCheckout(context);
                                        } 
                                      }else{
                                         _onButtonPressed(stockminimo); 
                                      }
                                     setState(() => _isButtonDisabled = !_isButtonDisabled);
                                  },
                                  disabledColor: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
                                  color:
                                      !_con.carts[0].product.market.closed ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                                  shape: StadiumBorder(),
                                  child: Text(
                                    S.of(context).checkout,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                                child: Helper.getPrice(
                                  _con.total,
                                  context,
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.merge(TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Please share some code so we can help. Thanks

Comment: onPressed: () {
          if (currentUser.value.apiToken != null) {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .pushNamed('/Cart', arguments: RouteArgument(param: '/Product', id: widget.product.id));
          } else {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Login');
          }
        },

Comment: Can you also how you pop the shopping cart page?

Comment: I just updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Try using PushReplacementNamed here:

```
shape: StadiumBorder(),
onPressed: () {
  if (currentUser.value.apiToken != null) {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .pushNamed('/Cart', arguments: RouteArgument(param: '/Product', id: widget.product.id));
  } else {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Login');
  }
},
```